# Performant group by filtered by difference

Tags: mysql, performance, group-by

I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE "items" (
  "id" int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  "id_ur" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  "window_key" varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
  KEY "idx_window_key" ("window_key") USING BTREE,
  KEY "idx_id_ur" ("id_ur") USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This table contains 19 000 00 of rows.

I need to select all records that share the `id_ur` field with a different `window_key`.
For instance, if I had records like the following:

```
id,id_ur,window_key
1,"123","ABC"
2,"124","DEF"
3,"123","ABD"
4,"124","DEF"
```

I would need to return "123", and not "124".

I'm looking for a performant way to do this in MySQL Community Server, version 5.7.22.

I tried the following :

```
select c1.id_ur
from items c1
inner join items c2
on c1.id_ur = c2.id_ur
where c1.window_key <> c2.window_key;
```

But it's not really performant.
I've tried to express it using a group by clause, but I don't know how to express the grouping of rows that are not different on a specific column.

I have indexes on both `id_ur` and `window_key` fields. I'm not sure if adding an index on both fields would be useful or not.

I'm looking for a decent query to get these records.

---

Thanks to some help I received I was able to find more performant solutions.

This is the result of the benchmark:

```
select distinct c1.id_ur
from item c1, item c2
where c1.id_ur = c2.id_ur
and c1.window_key <> c2.window_key
-- 1483 secs

select c1.id_ur
from item c1
inner item c2
on c1.id_ur = c2.id_ur
where c1.window_key <> c2.window_key;
 -- 675 secs

select distinct c1.id_ur
from item c1
group by c1.id_ur
having count(distinct c1.window_key) > 1
-- 170 secs

SELECT dt.id_ur 
FROM 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT c1.id_ur, c1.window_key 
  FROM gbmlive.canonical AS c1
) AS dt 
GROUP BY dt.id_ur 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
-- 376 secs
```

So the fastest solution was a group by with a distinct count.

Comment: When using `Group By` on a field, you don't need to use `Distinct` clause on the same field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `group by` and `having` at the same time :

```
select id_user
from items
group by id_user
having count(distinct window_key) > 1
```

Comment: And to make it even faster, change `INDEX(id_user)` to `INDEX(id_user, window_key)`.  This would be a "covering index".

Answer (score 2):

*@FatemehNB*'s answer is good. Besides that, you can also try the following query and compare performance:

```
SELECT dt.id_ur 
FROM 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT c1.id_ur, c1.window_key 
  FROM items AS c1
) AS dt 
GROUP BY dt.id_ur 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: F's query does the task in a single pass (plus `GROUP BY` overhead).  Your subquery is roughly 2 passes, and 2 `GROUP BYs` (one disguised as `DISTINCT`).

Comment: @RickJames I know ; that's why I said that F's answer is good. It is just one more possible way and can help at times.